# String includes many substrings in ScalaTest Matchers

Tags: string, scala, scalatest, matcher

I need to check that one string contains many substrings. The following works

```
string should include ("seven")
string should include ("eight")
string should include ("nine")
```

but it takes three almost duplicated lines. I'm looking for something like

```
string should contain allOf ("seven", "eight", "nine")
```

however this doesn't work... The assertion just fails while string contains these substrings for sure.

How can I perform such assertion in one line?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
string should (include("seven") and include("eight") and include("nine"))
```

Answer (score 11):

You can always create a custom matcher:

```
it should "..." in {
  "str asd dsa ddsd" should includeAllOf ("r as", "asd", "dd")
}

def includeAllOf(expectedSubstrings: String*): Matcher[String] =
  new Matcher[String] {
    def apply(left: String): MatchResult =
      MatchResult(expectedSubstrings forall left.contains,
        s"""String "$left" did not include all of those substrings: ${expectedSubstrings.map(s => s""""$s"""").mkString(", ")}""",
        s"""String "$left" contained all of those substrings: ${expectedSubstrings.map(s => s""""$s"""").mkString(", ")}""")
  }
```

See http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#usingCustomMatchers for more details.